# URL shortcut target not updating

Tags: inno-setup

I have created an installer that prompts the user for an IP address, using this input it then creates a shortcut on the desktop. This works perfectly fine on the first try but if I delete the shortcut and run the installer again this time entering a completely different IP it creates the shortcut using the IP from the previous instance. This continues until I reboot my computer. Thoughts?

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\Test Icon name"; Filename: "http://{code:GetServerIPFromUserInput}/contentfolder/index.html";

[Code] 
function GetServerIPFromUserInput(Param: String): String;
begin
result :=  ServerNamePage.Values[0];
end;
```

Comment: Show us your `GetServerIPFromUserInput`.

Comment: I added it to my original post.